# Restarting Arduino and keeping the variables

Tags: arduino, restart

I would like to restart the arduino board but keeping values of some variable. My solution would be calling `setup()` whenever I would like to restart. Something like this:

```
int led = 13;
int led2 = 50;
boolean restart = false;

void setup() {     

  pinMode(led, OUTPUT); 
  pinMode(led2, OUTPUT); 

  if(!restart){
    digitalWrite(led, LOW);  // will only happen once
    delay(3000);
  }

  digitalWrite(led, HIGH);   // turn the LED on (and will be always on even after reset)
  restart = true;
  delay(3000);
  digitalWrite(led2, HIGH); // indicate restart is called
  delay(1000);
  digitalWrite(led2, LOW);
  setup();}

void loop() {         }
```

I was thinking if this will cause any heavy usage in RAM. Or is there any better methods?

Thank you.

Comment: Calling setup() from inside setup() will lead to a stack overflow. (And yes, that will use up all the RAM.)

Comment: well, perhaps not in setup(), but once a while in loop()....(e.g. when some buttons are pressed/ in some situation the code as to start again from the beginning)

Comment: As UncleO said, the code as it is, will certainly cause a stack overflow (BTW: loop() will never run)

Comment: Why would you need to restart an arduino?

Comment: I am using Arduino with GSM shield, such that it takes readings and return back to server(PC). But sometimes the GSM shield disconnects, and I would like to restart the Arduino and allowing it to connect to server again....

Answer (score 0):

Use the EEPROM library. Have a button with an interrupt that saves the variable then read the variable in the setup() routine.

If you are getting or changing information slow enough you could constantly write the value but beware EEPROM on this chip is only certified to 100,000 writes per byte.

Comment: I was not hoping to use the EEPROM, as it can only write up to 100,000 times....(not a long term solution?..)

Comment: How often do you need to retain data? If you save once per hour you will start to have failures in 11yrs. This can be extended hugely by writing in different sectors each time to use the entire EEPROM area. It will always depend on your use case. You could have an external socket EEPROM with a replacement schedule if you require more regular writes. At that point you could also use an sdcard and have even more flexibility.

Comment: How much data do you need to save and how often?